Error 404 in the discord bot console when there is an interaction extension
There is the following code:
bot.py:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import logging
import os
import asyncio
from config import settings

discord.utils.setup_logging(level=logging.INFO,root=True)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'],intents=discord.Intents.all()) # Так как мы указали префикс в settings, обращаемся к словарю с ключом prefix.
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    synced = await bot.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=1283589491298402314))
    print(f'Синхронизированно {len(synced)} команд!')
    print(bot.guilds)

async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            if filename != '__init__.py':
                await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

async def main():
    await load()
    await bot.start(settings['token'])


asyncio.run(main())

Utils.py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

class UtilsCommand(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot:discord.Client):
        self.bot=bot

    @app_commands.command(name='ping',description='Check ping')
    async def ping(self,interaction:discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        await interaction.followup.send(content=f"Pong! ({str(self.bot.latency)[2:5]})")

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(UtilsCommand(bot),guild=discord.Object(id=1283589491298402314))

When calling the ping command, the bot can send a 3-digit number or throw the error "discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'ping' raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction" and send a long real number
what the error looks like in discord
What’s also interesting is that if the answer is adequately output (a 3-digit number), their values ​​are very often repeated, 3 or even 5 times.
strange behavior, I very much doubt that the ping is so stable
Please tell me what could be causing this behavior of the bot?  And how can this strangeness be eliminated?
I tried to google this error, but all I found were words about responding to an interaction within 3 seconds, or extending it.
I don’t think at all that the problem is the delay in response to interaction, since the ping would then be much higher.
Traceback:
[2024-09-15 00:43:13] [ERROR   ] discord.app_commands.tree: Ignoring exception in command 'ping'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyProject\Jack\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 857, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(self.binding, interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyProject\Jack\cogs\Utils.py", line 13, in ping
    await interaction.response.send_message(content=f"Pong! ({latency})",ephemeral=True)
  File "D:\PyProject\Jack\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\interactions.py", line 855, in send_message
    await adapter.create_interaction_response(
  File "D:\PyProject\Jack\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\webhook\async_.py", line 221, in request
    raise NotFound(response, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyProject\Jack\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1310, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "D:\PyProject\Jack\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 883, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyProject\Jack\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 876, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'ping' raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction


Traceback screenshot

Please post the full traceback.

The problem was that bot.start(settings['token']) can launch several copies of the bot at the same time with 1 token. Because of this, Schrödinger interaction may occur.
The problem can be solved if, after turning off the bot, you wait a while for it to turn off in Discord.
You can also use run rather than start, so you don’t have to wait,
until the bot turns off
